# Context managers and multiprocessing pools

Tags: python, multiprocessing, contextmanager

Suppose you are using a `multiprocessing.Pool` object, and you are using the `initializer` setting of the constructor to pass an initializer function that then creates a resource in the global namespace. Assume resource has a context manager. How would you handle the life-cycle of the context managed resource provided it has to live through the life of the process, but be properly cleaned up at the end?

So far, I have something somewhat like this:

```
resource_cm = None
resource = None


def _worker_init(args):
    global resource
    resource_cm = open_resource(args)
    resource = resource_cm.__enter__()
```

From here on, the pool processes can use the resource. So far so good. But handling clean up is a bit trickier, since the `multiprocessing.Pool` class does not provide a `destructor` or `deinitializer` argument.

One of my ideas is to use the `atexit` module, and register the clean up in the initializer. Something like this:

```
def _worker_init(args):
    global resource
    resource_cm = open_resource(args)
    resource = resource_cm.__enter__()

    def _clean_up():
        resource_cm.__exit__()

    import atexit
    atexit.register(_clean_up)
```

Is this a good approach? Is there an easier way of doing this?

EDIT: `atexit` does not seem to work. At least not in the way I am using it above, so as of right now I still do not have a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First, this is a really great question! After digging around a bit in the `multiprocessing` code, I think I've found a way to do this:

When you start a `multiprocessing.Pool`, internally the `Pool` object creates a `multiprocessing.Process` object for each member of the pool. When those sub-processes are starting up, they call a `_bootstrap` function, which looks like this:

```
def _bootstrap(self):
    from . import util
    global _current_process
    try:
        # ... (stuff we don't care about)
        util._finalizer_registry.clear()
        util._run_after_forkers()
        util.info('child process calling self.run()')
        try:
            self.run()
            exitcode = 0 
        finally:
            util._exit_function()
        # ... (more stuff we don't care about)
```

The `run` method is what actually runs the `target` you gave the `Process` object. For a `Pool` process that's a method with a long-running while loop that waits for work items to come in over an internal queue. What's really interesting for us is what happened *after* `self.run`: `util._exit_function()` is called.

As it turns out, that function does some clean up that sounds a lot like what you're looking for:

```
def _exit_function(info=info, debug=debug, _run_finalizers=_run_finalizers,
                   active_children=active_children,
                   current_process=current_process):
    # NB: we hold on to references to functions in the arglist due to the
    # situation described below, where this function is called after this
    # module's globals are destroyed.

    global _exiting

    info('process shutting down')
    debug('running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0')  # Very interesting!
    _run_finalizers(0)
```

Here's the docstring of `_run_finalizers`:

```
def _run_finalizers(minpriority=None):
    '''
    Run all finalizers whose exit priority is not None and at least minpriority

    Finalizers with highest priority are called first; finalizers with
    the same priority will be called in reverse order of creation.
    '''
```

The method actually runs through a list of finalizer callbacks and executes them:

```
items = [x for x in _finalizer_registry.items() if f(x)]
items.sort(reverse=True)

for key, finalizer in items:
    sub_debug('calling %s', finalizer)
    try:
        finalizer()
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Perfect. So how do we get into the `_finalizer_registry`? There's an undocumented object called `Finalize` in `multiprocessing.util` that is responsible for adding a callback to the registry:

```
class Finalize(object):
    '''
    Class which supports object finalization using weakrefs
    '''
    def __init__(self, obj, callback, args=(), kwargs=None, exitpriority=None):
        assert exitpriority is None or type(exitpriority) is int

        if obj is not None:
            self._weakref = weakref.ref(obj, self)
        else:
            assert exitpriority is not None

        self._callback = callback
        self._args = args
        self._kwargs = kwargs or {}
        self._key = (exitpriority, _finalizer_counter.next())
        self._pid = os.getpid()

        _finalizer_registry[self._key] = self  # That's what we're looking for!
```

Ok, so putting it all together into an example:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.util import Finalize

resource_cm = None
resource = None

class Resource(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args

    def __enter__(self):
        print("in __enter__ of %s" % multiprocessing.current_process())
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("in __exit__ of %s" % multiprocessing.current_process())

def open_resource(args):
    return Resource(args)

def _worker_init(args):
    global resource
    print("calling init")
    resource_cm = open_resource(args)
    resource = resource_cm.__enter__()
    # Register a finalizer
    Finalize(resource, resource.__exit__, exitpriority=16)

def hi(*args):
    print("we're in the worker")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=_worker_init, initargs=("abc",))
    pool.map(hi, range(pool._processes))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Output:

```
calling init
in __enter__ of <Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
calling init
calling init
in __enter__ of <Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
in __enter__ of <Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
calling init
in __enter__ of <Process(PoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
we're in the worker
we're in the worker
we're in the worker
we're in the worker
in __exit__ of <Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
in __exit__ of <Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
in __exit__ of <Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
in __exit__ of <Process(PoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
```

As you can see `__exit__` gets called in all our workers when we `join()` the pool.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how to decide on the value for `exitpriority`? i.e. in your case it is `exitpriority=16`

Answer (score 5):

You can subclass `Process` and override its `run()` method so that it performs cleanup before exit. Then you should subclass `Pool` so that it uses your subclassed process:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

class SafeProcess(Process):
    """ Process that will cleanup before exit """
    def run(self, *args, **kw):
        result = super().run(*args, **kw)
        # cleanup however you want here
        return result


class SafePool(Pool):
    Process = SafeProcess


pool = SafePool(4)  # use it as standard Pool
```

Comment: @nattster I like this approach better than the previous one, even though it uses built-in machinery for this, because of the elegance. But when I try it, I get a `TypeError: method expected 2 arguments, got 3` at the `class SafePool(Pool):` line. Any ideas?

Comment: @MilindR python version? I used Python 2.

Comment: @MilindR, I think I figured out why you are getting that error. Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70572544/3158248. Basically `multiprocessing.Pool` is a function so you will need to subclass `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with. It uses [billiard](https://github.com/celery/billiard) which is a fork of Python's multiprocessing package. This solution requires use of private API `Worker._ensure_messages_consumed` so I **DO NOT** recommend using this solution in production. I just need this for a side project so this is good enough for me. Use this at your own risk.

```
from billiard import pool
from billiard.pool import Pool, Worker

class SafeWorker(Worker):
    # this function is called just before a worker process exits
    def _ensure_messages_consumed(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Not necessary, but you can move `Pool.initializer` logic here if you want.
        out = super()._ensure_messages_consumed(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do clean up work here
        return out

class SafePool(Pool):
    Worker = SafeWorker
```

Another solution I tried was to implement my clean up logic as a signal handler, but that does not work since both `multiprocessing` and `billiard` use `exit()` to kill their worker processes. I'm not sure how `atexit` works but this is probably the reason that approach does not work either.