# profiling python multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, profiling, python-multiprocessing

I've got some code that is using a `Pool` from Python's `multiprocessing` module.  Performance isn't what I expect and wanted to profile the code to figure out what's happening.  The problem I'm having is that the profiling output gets overwritten for each job and I can't accumulate a sensible amount of stats.

For example, with:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import cProfile
import time
import random

def work(i):
    x = random.random()
    time.sleep(x)
    return (i,x)

def work_(args):
    out = [None]
    cProfile.runctx('out[0] = work(args)', globals(), locals(),
                    'profile-%s.out' % mp.current_process().name)
    return out[0]

pool = mp.Pool(10)

for i in pool.imap_unordered(work_, range(100)):
    print(i)
```

I only get stats on the "last" job, which may not be the most computationally demanding one.  I presume I need to store the stats somewhere and then only write them out when the pool is being cleaned up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocess profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041683/python-multiprocess-profiling)

Comment: @ChrisWithers don't think any of those answers help much.  these days I think I'd use something like https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene which (AFAIK) didn't exist back in 2015. maybe I should post an answer here or there mentioning Scalene as I'm not sure how much people know about it

Comment: Hmm, this maybe some kind of weird automatic SO thing. I suggested this question be closed as a dupe of that one so we can concentrate "how do I profile multiprocessing pools in Python?" answers in one place.

Answer (score 2):

My solution involves holding onto a profile object for longer and only writing it out at the "end".  Hooking into the Pool teardown is described [better elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24724452/1358308), but involves using a `Finalize` object to execute `dump_stats()` explicitly at the appropriate time.

This also allows me to tidy up the awkward `work_` trampoline needed with the `runctx` I was using before.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import cProfile
import time
import random

def work(i):
    # enable profiling (refers to the global object below)
    prof.enable()
    x = random.random()
    time.sleep(x)
    # disable so we don't profile the Pool
    prof.disable()
    return (i,x)

# Initialise a good profile object and make sure it gets written during Pool teardown
def _poolinit():
    global prof
    prof = cProfile.Profile()
    def fin():
        prof.dump_stats('profile-%s.out' % mp.current_process().pid)

    mp.util.Finalize(None, fin, exitpriority=1)

# create our pool
pool = mp.Pool(10, _poolinit)

for i in pool.imap_unordered(work, range(100)):
    print(i)
```

Loading the output shows that multiple invocations were indeed recorded:

```
> p = pstats.Stats("profile-ForkPoolWorker-5.out")
> p.sort_stats("time").print_stats(10)
Fri Sep 11 12:11:58 2015    profile-ForkPoolWorker-5.out

         30 function calls in 4.684 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       10    4.684    0.468    4.684    0.468 {built-in method sleep}
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) you can use the `pid` attribute to get a unique name for each output file

```
cProfile.runctx('out[0] = work(args)', globals(), locals(),
                'profile-%s-%s.out' % (mp.current_process().pid, datetime.now().isoformat()))
```

Comment: the problem is that `runctx` overwrites the output on every invocation, because it's executed multiple times you only get the "last" job for each process—about to post a semi-working solution

Comment: ah ok - it's over written per-process - why not just add a timestamp?

Comment: because I have *lots* of jobs being executed in real life and I don't want millions of small profile files