# Python multiprocessor pool post-process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a set of tasks to be executed (to the tune of millions) and I have to `POST` the result of each "execution". The POST offers me a way to batch the results.

I have the following skeleton :

```py
def init_pool_processes():
    global gathered_data
    gathered_data = []

class Generate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dummy = 0
    def __call__(self, message):
        print (f'processing for {message}')
        # message processed. Assume the result is message
        gathered_data.append(message)
        if len(gathered_data) == 3:
            # POST gathered data with a batch of (say) 3 and
            # clear as we do not need it any more
            gathered_data.clear()
    def process (self, message):
        try:
            pool = Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes)
            pool.map(self, message)
        finally:
            pool.close()
            pool.join()


def func():
    message = ['This', 'is', 'the', 'end', 'my', 'only', 'friend', 'thee', 'eend', '.']         
    obj = Generate()
    obj.process(message)
    print ('Processing done!!!')


func()
```

Now clearly, some executions at the end might not end up in the POST call. So I need a way to call a function (once) for each worker that was created.

I tried adding the following after the map call :

```py
pool.map(post_process, list(range(pool._processes)), chunksize=1)
```

but this does not guarantee that the function post_process will be called for all workers.

Any pointers on how to achieve this? I want to avoid a global queue/timer solutions if possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Context managers and multiprocessing pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717468/context-managers-and-multiprocessing-pools). In particular see the accepted answer to that question.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you eschew queues?  They are an easy an efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: @lxop The suggested answer works. However, it uses a `exitpriority` which I am not able to find any documentation for. Any link I can take a look at? Thanks!

Comment: Just from looking at the code in that answer, I see that `exitpriority` has a default value of `None`, so I would leave it out completely. I believe it just allows a user to specify multiple finalizers and set an order for them, but in your case you don't have any ordering requirements (you only have one), so you have no need to use it at all.